# How to add category ID in get_option function

Tags: php, wordpress

**UPDATE**
I did some research and learned that I can save fields to term meta in database instead to options as I was doing at the beginning and easily output it. But I'm doing something wrong with saving since there are no entries in term meta table. Could you look at my code and point out my mistakes?

```
<?php 
 function realized_category_field( $term ){
 $term_id = $term->term_id;
 $term_meta = get_term_meta('realized');
?>
 <tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row">
        <label for="term_meta[realized]"><?php echo _e('Has the project been implemented?') ?></label>
        <td>
            <select name="term_meta[realized]" id="term_meta[realized]">
                <option value="0" <?=($term_meta['realized'] === 0) ? 'selected': ''?>><?php echo _e('NO'); ?></option>
                <option value="1" <?=($term_meta['realized'] === 1) ? 'selected': ''?>><?php echo _e('YES'); ?></option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </th>
  </tr>
 <?php
  }

  // Add the dropdown to the Edit form
  add_action( 'category_edit_form_fields', 'realized_category_field' );

  // Save the field
  function realized_save_term_meta() {
     $term_id = $term->term_id;
     $old = get_term_meta($term_id, 'realized', true);
     $new = $_POST['realized'];

     if ( $new && $new !== $old ) {
       update_term_meta( $term_id, 'realized', $new );
     } elseif ( '' === $new && $old ) {
       delete_term_meta( $term_id, 'realized', $old );
     }
   }
  add_action('edited_category', 'category_edit_form_fields');

  function realized_category_columns_values( $deprecated, $column_name, $term_id) {

  if($column_name === 'realized'){
   $term_meta = get_term_meta('realized');
    if($term_meta['realized'] === 1){
     echo _e('YES');
    }else{
     echo _e('NO');
    }
  }
 }

 add_action( 'manage_category_custom_column' , 'realized_category_columns_values', 10, 3 );

// Add column to Category list

function realized_category_columns($columns)
{
  return array_merge($columns, array('realized' =>  __('Has the project been implemented?')));
}

add_filter('manage_edit-category_columns' , 'realized_category_columns');
?>
```

I wanted to create a drop down list to define if a category was closed or not and check that up in a query later on and print only the opened categories.

I fallowed this [tutorial](https://php.quicoto.com/add-metadata-categories-wordpress/) to achieve the first part of my code, but I got stuck with outputting the data and checking if the category is opened or closed.

My problem is that I don't know how to pass the `term_id` to `$terms`, and also I'm not sure if I wrote the if statement correct.

Could someone please help me out?

```
 <?php
       $args = array(
           'show_option_all'    => '',
           'orderby'            => 'ID',
           'order'              => 'ASC',
       );

       $categories = get_categories($args);
       $terms = get_option('taxonomy_'.$categories['term_id']);

       echo '<ul class="realized-projects-category-list">';
         foreach($categories as $category) {
          if ($terms['taxonomy_'.$category->term_id]  === '1') {
            echo '<li>';
             echo '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';
            echo '</li>';
         }
       }
       echo '</ul>';
     ?>
```

Comment: this condition is wrong please rectify this  if ($term['taxonomy_'.$category->term_id]  === '1') { there is no array available with the name of $term but available with $terms, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes, it should be terms. I did a var_dump for the `$terms` and I got this `bool(false)`